# Access data from setting Model cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

If I am setting the Post model in my controller as follows;

```
    $this->Post->id = $id;
```

Can I access the data from Post or do I have to perform execute;

```
     $this->Post->read()
```

I'd like to perform some further validation on Post to determine the logic which is being executed.

e.g. If the Post['submitted_by'] = $this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin') **"pseudo code"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code :

```
$data = $this->Post->read(null, $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read() to access the data.

It's the way the MVC works ([more info there](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html)).

```
$this->Post->id = $id;
```

This code modifies the  view instance, and that's all. You need another function to link the view to the database.